# Why does MySQL not ORDER as expected?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a pretty simple MySQL table with team names and id. Team names looks as shown below:

```
Damer
F11
F12
F15
Herrar
HJ18
HJ20
P15
P16
P11
P12
P8
...
```

But when I order by ASC or DESC based on teamnames I do not get them in the order i would expect, something like above. Instead I get a list like this:

```
P15
P16
Damer
F11
F12
F15
Herrar
HJ18
HJ20
P11
P12
P8
...
```

This makes no sense, why does MySQL start with two names that start with P then one taht starts with D followed by three that starts with F... and finally ends with three teams that start with P again.

Any idea?

MySQL code:

```
SELECT *
FROM `team`
ORDER BY `team`.`teamname` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And I am using mysql collation utf8_swedish_ci.

Comment: Do you have any spaces before the first letter in some of those names/

Comment: What charset is table, database and fields?

Comment: @JohnConde And it was that easy! Jesus! Didn't see, but it seems like some teamsnames have an accidental white space in front of them. Feel free to give that answer and I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: @jamietelin - done as requested! Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a space before the first character in the names that are out of order.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes the answer is so obvious its hard to see.